# Unable to handle net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, exception, react-hooks, axios

I am trying a post request to http://localhost:5000/run. If the server is not running then trying to throw "Please retry again" to client.

```
try{
    const {data} = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/run",payload);
    setOutput(data.output);
}
catch ({ response }) {
  if (response) {
    const errMsg = response.data.err.stderr;
    setOutput(errMsg);
  } else {
    setOutput("Please retry submitting.");
  }
}
```

[image]

when the server is running proper error is received but not when the server is offline. Anything missing from the code?

Comment: You are immediately destructuring `response` out of the error with the line `catch ({ response })`, but error.response will not exist if the server is offline.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {AxiosError} from 'axios';

    axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/run", payload)
        .then((response) => setOutput(response.data.output))
        .catch((error) => {
            if (!error?.response) {
                setOutput("No Server Response");
            } else if (error?.code === AxiosError.ERR_NETWORK) {
                setOutput("Network Error");
            } else if (error.response?.status === 404) {
                setOutput("404 - Not Found");
            } else if (error?.code) {
                setOutput("Code: " + error.code);
            } else {
                setOutput("Unknown Error");
            }
        });
```

You can use `axios.isAxiosError(error)` to make sure that the error is type of AxiosError.

Axios error types:

```
static readonly ERR_FR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS = "ERR_FR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS";
static readonly ERR_BAD_OPTION_VALUE = "ERR_BAD_OPTION_VALUE";
static readonly ERR_BAD_OPTION = "ERR_BAD_OPTION";
static readonly ERR_NETWORK = "ERR_NETWORK";
static readonly ERR_DEPRECATED = "ERR_DEPRECATED";
static readonly ERR_BAD_RESPONSE = "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE";
static readonly ERR_BAD_REQUEST = "ERR_BAD_REQUEST";
static readonly ERR_CANCELED = "ERR_CANCELED";
static readonly ECONNABORTED = "ECONNABORTED";
static readonly ETIMEDOUT = "ETIMEDOUT";
```

Comment: when the server is offline it is executing `setOutput("Something went wrong. (Like CORS)");` instead of `setOutput("Error: Network Error");`

Comment: @KhagenBorah
you're right. Thank you for response.
I updated my answer and hope it is useful for you.
If it was useful for you, please click on the 'accept this answer' button on the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try using `response.response.data.error` for displaying error in your case instead of `response.data.err.stderr`. So here you are getting error data from response :

```
try{
    const {data} = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/run",payload);
    setOutput(data.output);
}
catch ({ response }) {
  if (response) {
    const errMsg = response.response.data.error;
    setOutput(errMsg);
  } else {
    setOutput("Please retry submitting.");
  }
}
```

Reference discussion [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/376).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the comments, this is the solution that ended up working:

```
try {
  const {data} = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/run", payload);
  setOutput(data.output);
} catch (error) {
  if (error.response.data) {
    setOutput(error.response.data.err.stderr);
  } else {
    setOutput("Error connecting to the server!");
  }
}
```